# Returning to a page from window.location.href=url

Tags: javascript

I have a web site builder with a Publish button that puts the constructed web site out at a designated url. I would then like to perform the courtesy of transferring the user to the built page. I can use window.open(url), which opens a new window with the new site and leaves the editor page in tact. So after seeing the built page the user can just close it and be back in the editor to make more changes after seeing what was built.  This is the ideal solution, except that it doesn't work with Safari because it blocks pop ups.

The other possibility is to execute window.location.href=url. This gets the user to the new page but getting back to the editor and its previous state is not clean.  Hitting the back button from the new site reloads the editor page without any of the state information the user had built up to moment of publishing.

Is there a way I can get the user back to editor with the previous state information displayed, that works for Firefox and Safari?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an anchor tag with the `target` set to "_blank" to open the built page in a new tab/window. The potential downside of this is that the browser decides the size of the new window, whether a window or new tab is used, etc.

```
<a href="/constructedsite" target="_blank">View site</a>
```

Comment: That's excellent! It works great.  I must be under a lucky star here because I get full new windows in both Firefox and Safari and the original edit page is left in tact in the browser. Thanks.